# Find function in excel: search by keyword

Tags: forms, visual-studio-2010, excel, vba

I have a form in which you introduce the product code and it returns its description and price. I would like to add another search criteria to be able to look for the product by keyword, searching in the "description" column. I'm not sure whether the "find" function allows doing this, or if I need to use the "vlookup" function. The problem that I found with "vlookup" is that I would like to be able to keep searching in the column for the rest of the matchs. This is the code that I have working at the moment:

```
Option Explicit
Dim Llave As Boolean
Private Sub BtnBuscar_Click()
If Not Sheet1.Range("C1:C211").Find(Me.DatoBuscado, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole) Is Nothing Then
If Llave Then
  Cells.FindNext(After:=ActiveCell).Select
  Fila.Caption = ActiveCell.Row
  Dato1.Caption = ActiveCell.Value
  Dato2.Caption = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value
  Dato3.Caption = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Value
  Dato4.Caption = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 4).Value

Else
 Sheet1.Range("C1:C211").Find(Me.DatoBuscado, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole).Select
 Fila.Caption = Sheet1.Range("C:C").Find(Me.DatoBuscado, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole).Row
 Dato1.Caption = Sheet1.Range("C:C").Find(Me.DatoBuscado, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole).Value
 Dato2.Caption = Sheet1.Range("C:C").Find(Me.DatoBuscado, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole).Offset(0, 1).Value
 Dato3.Caption = Sheet1.Range("C:C").Find(Me.DatoBuscado, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole).Offset(0, 2).Value
 Dato4.Caption = Sheet1.Range("C:C").Find(Me.DatoBuscado, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole).Offset(0, 4).Value
 Llave = True
End If

Else
  Dato1.Caption = "   "
  Dato2.Caption = "   "
  Dato3.Caption = "   "
  Dato4.Caption = "   "
  Fila.Caption = "    "
  MsgBox "Dato Inexistente", 64, ""
End If
End Sub



Private Sub Dato1_Click()

End Sub

Private Sub Dato3_Click()

End Sub

Private Sub Fila_Click()

End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
 Llave = False
End Sub
```

So it's a search form (Userform) that I pop up when clicking a button on the worksheet (shee1).

Thanks a lot in advance!

Natalia.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using Find in a DO UNTIL loop until the range returned by find is nothing and use that loop to populate a listbox.  Then the user can select the match that the want.

Comment: but I think the Find function needs as input the exact string that you are looking for, so I would like to look for a keyword inside the string. Is that possible by using Find? Thanks :)

Comment: You can set Find to search for the whole or a partial string.  Use parameter `LookAt:=xlPart`.